# What comes after the ducentiquinquagintasexions?

Tags: mathematics, latin

[Hypercomplex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomplex_number) that use the [Cayley-Dickson construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction) seem to follow a Latin naming convention related to the size of the algebra (which is always a power of two). As an English.SE question, I'm interested in the larger names that I haven't been able to find on the web. Here is what I know:

- [Quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) (4-ions)
- [Octonions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion) (8-ions)
- [Sedenions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedenion) (16-ions)
- Trigintaduonions (32-ions)
- Sexagintaquatronions (64-ions)
- Centumduodetrigintanions (128-ions)
- Ducentiquinquagintasexions (256-ions)

What would the next higher orders be following this naming scheme?

- ??? (512-ions)
- ??? (1024-ions)
- ??? (2048-ions)
- ??? (4096-ions)

Comment: As an aside, we know the 2-ions as [complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) and the 1-ions as the [real numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number), which don't follow the convention (perhaps since they are so common).

Comment: "I found that 512D should be named hyper-complex Voudon.  And, 1024D should be named hyper-quaternion Voudon.  I found no new mathematics after 1024 because higher hypercomplex numbers greater than 1024 are cyclic (they repeat all over again).  I do not offer dimensions higher than 256D to the publc Maple Application Center because the mathematics is very slow and time cosuming past 64D." [mapleprimes.com](http://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/124913-Visualization-Of-The-CayleyDickson)

Comment: Any of these beyond octonions are so rarely used that,even if they have names, those names would not be used in mathematical writing about them.

Comment: @ermanen The usage of "voudon" and the others listed seem to come from   a paper by Robert P. C. de Marrais and lack any consistency to predict the next order term. _This question_ is a English (Latin)-based one following the "rules" that seem to be present in the naming scheme.

Comment: @Hooked: It is mentioned that they simplified some of the terms and it is explained that it is unnecessary to go beyond a certain point. Do you really need this information or is it just trivia? If you really need terms for these, simplified versions would be easier to read :)  (and the next question: 8192, 16384, 32768 ...)

Comment: @GEdgar while I defer to your mathematical expertise (and I agree that without usage it is unlikely to warrant a permanent name) I thought that the question of the _naming itself_ was an interesting, if academic, exercise. The motivation stemmed from a small project I made last night to [visualize](https://github.com/thoppe/Cayley-Dickson) the multiplication tables. I felt that calling them 512-ions was just so _pedestrian_.

Comment: @ermanen Even if they are cyclic at 1024, this still leaves the first two terms listed in the question unnamed. From the comment by GEdgar, you'll note that this is a bit of "trivia" if you will -- but I thought the question was interesting enough to learn some Latin from a few commonly accepted terms already (like quaternions and octonions) and thus enough merit for a question here at English.SE.

Comment: I think we should call them `absurd`, `preposterous`, `ludicrous`, and `insane`. Seriously. By the time we get to sedenions, the Algebra isn't even associative, let alone commutative. Just useless. And this from a pure mathematician.

Comment: The real question here is, since we'll probably only ever use the digits once we get past sedonions, why shouldn't it be 32-_nions_?

Comment: @imallett Reminded me of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap,_Crackle_and_Pop#Physics

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not relate remotely to everyday English; such arcane usages might be acceptable on Maths if the question were closed and resubmitted there.

Comment: What?  You don't get enough of a charge out of 256 ions??

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about very rarefied (if even extant) usage. I'm not sure it even fits on Mathematics,SE.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth respectfully, it is a question about an English word and Latin construction with (what I feel and the votes reflect) a quality answer. You've tried to close this question 3 years ago already and it didn't hold - if nothing substantially changed why try again?

Comment: @Hooked There are few tokens of 'Ducentiquinquagintasexions' found in a Google search. It's not found in domains outside science/maths except where questions like this are asked ... there's nothing in everyday domains. ELU is about standard English usages. This and further derivatives aren't. I think '2,4-dinitrophenylhydrazines' was also seen as off-topic on ELU.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm afraid the words you mention were already formed incorrectly and inconsistently.

I see some were formed from distributive numbers + an unknown suffix -*ion* (like *quaternion*).

Others were formed from cardinal numbers + -*nion* (like *trigintaduonions*)

Others again were formed from a cardinal number + something that doesn't look like a Latin word + a suffix that looks like -*onion* (*sexagintaquatronions*).

---

The ones that would be several separate words in Latin are the most problematic. Consider the cardinal number *triginta duo*, "thirty-two". Normally in Latin, if you wanted to turn that into a distributive number, you'd change both words into their distributive forms: *trigeni bini* "thirty-two each". Then if you want to add -ion to the stem of the last word and turn them into a single word, you will get *trigeni-bin-ion*.

The way some of the words in the list were formed, on the other hand, is by changing only the last word into a distributive number and keeping the other one(s) cardinal: *triginta-bin-ion*.

The Romans would normally write larger numbers as separate words. But, if we ignore that, using something based on all distributive numbers would seem closer to the Roman way, like *trigeni-bin-ion* above. I will provide both options; first I give [all distributive + *-ion*], then [cardinal(s) + distributive + *-ion*]:

> **Quaternions** (4-ions)
>   **Octonions** (8-ions)
>   **Sedenions** (16-ions)
>   **Tricenibinions** / trigintabinions  (32-ions)
>   **Sexageniquaternions** / sexagintaquaternions (64-ions)
>   **Centeniduodetricenions** / centumduodetricenions  (128-ions)
>   **Duceniquinquagenisenions** / ducentiquinquagintasenions (256-ions)
>
> **Quingeniduodenions** / quingentiduodenions (512-ions)
>   **Miliaviceniquaternions** / millevigintiquaternions (1024-ions)
>   **Binamiliaduodequinquagenions** / duomiliaduodequinquagenions (2048-ions)
>   **Quaternamilianonagenisenions** / quattuormilianonagintasenions (4096-ions)

Note that distributive forms of thousand in Latin are a bit different from lower numbers, and I couldn't find any examples of their use combined with lower numbers: I only found passages with "three thousand each" in the HP Latin corpus, not e.g. "three thousand two hundred each". Note also that in Latin some words have two (or more) alternative forms, like *triceni/trigeni* "thirty each"; I have used the commonest alternative in each case.

Comment: thank you for the info! With this in mind, can you formulate all of the terms, from the 2-ions to the 4096-ions, using the rule of "distributive numbers + unknown suffix -ion" like the _quaternion_?

Comment: `something that doesn't look like Latin word` I beg your pardon? "sexāgintā" IS [latin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Latin_cardinal_numerals)

Comment: @Federico: Sexaginta is a Latin word, but not if you add quatr-something to it. (Of course I ignored the fact that the Romans would never have stuck large numbers together to form single words in the first place: I conceded that to English liberty. But then the Latin words on which it is based should at least be in the right form.)

Comment: @Hooked: OK done!

Comment: @Cerberus This is great, thank you! It is also part of the impetus for why I asked the question. Without knowing it, it highlighted a problem with the current naming scheme and gave me a little Latin lesson. Also, for posterity, it's worth noting that all of your new coinages are completely new to Google.

Comment: @Hooked: Haha, I am nor surprised, for who would use such words?

Comment: no, sexagintaquattuor is latin again, read [all that wiki page](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Latin_cardinal_numerals#Compound_cardinals) or [ask google](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=sexagintaquattuor)

Comment: @Federico: There is no "quattuor" in the cited word: it says "quatronion", which cannot be traced back to a normal Latin numeral (stem), that I know of.

Answer (score 6):

Following the Latin prefix tables from [phrontistery's reference](http://phrontistery.info/numbers.html), they would probably be:

512-ion: Quincentumduodecion
1024-ion: Millevigequaternion
2048-ion: Duomillequadragoction
4096-ion: Quadrimillenonagesextion

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about here, but +1 for the effort.

Comment: I'm afraid those look even less like English words formed based on proper Latin numerals, but bravo for daring to try...

Answer (score 5):

I propose an alternative convention: since each level is achieved by applying the **Ca**yley-**Di**ckson Construction to the previous, use numerical prefixes logarithmically and add the contraction -cadi-.  (Use Greek prefixes, to further avoid confusion with the original system which uses Latin.)  An *n*-cadinion will have 2<sup>*n*</sup> dimensions.  So a Quaternion, could also be called a Dicadinion and so forth:

- Complex = Monocadinion (2<sup>1</sup> = 2 dimensions)
- Quaternion = Dicadinion (2<sup>2</sup> = 4 dimensions)
- Octonion = Tricadinion (2<sup>3</sup> = 8 dimensions)
- Sedenion = Tetracadinion (2<sup>4</sup> = 16 dimensions)
- Trigintaduonion = Pentacadinion (2<sup>5</sup> = 32 dimensions)
- Sexagintaquatronion = Hexacadinion (2<sup>6</sup> = 64 dimensions)
- Centumduodetrigintanion = Heptacadinion (2<sup>7</sup> = 128 dimensions)
- Ducentiquinquagintasexion = Octocadinion (2<sup>8</sup> = 256 dimensions)

Next would be:

- Ennecadinion (2<sup>9</sup> = 512 dimensions)
- Dekacadinion (2<sup>10</sup> = 1024 dimensions)
- Hendekacadinion (2<sup>11</sup> = 2048 dimensions)
- Dodekacadinion (2<sup>12</sup> = 4096 dimensions)
- Tridekacadinion (2<sup>13</sup> = 8192 dimensions)

...and so on.

Comment: These logarithmic prefixes are short, which makes it less of a mouthful than "Ducentiquinquagintasexions".